# Mysql unique constraint > 16 columns

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique

I want to use normalization as much as I can. However, just can't wrap my head around this one.

Suppose I have financial data as such:

ledger# | dimension1 | dimension2 | dimension3

4000    | 100  |      200  |         300

5113    | 100  |      298  |         300

I need to be sure that every combination of these 4 columns is unique. I know about the unique constraint, so I put a 'unique' on all the mentioned columns.

But...what if the number of dimension columns has to be 25, so there will be 25 dimension columns instead of the 3 mentioned? How would I go around as to use a unique constraint? I know a constraint can hold only hold 16 columns or 3072 bytes, no more.

I was thinking of using a hash of some sort, but haven't quite figured out how to do that.

can anyone help me by providing an idea / info / example?

If there is a totally different idea of accomplishing this without a unique constraint, I'm all for hearing about it!

Comment: If you're totally mad you could try recompiling MySQL with different limits or use a different RDBMS like Postgres. A slack way to do this is to combine all the values in a singular key using SHA1 and use that as your uniqueness constraint if that's an acceptable outcome.

Comment: Using the hash as a unique constraint solves the problem (use triggers to populate the value) however how often does this happen in practice?

Comment: Just a dumb guess, but it looks like ledger# is the only thing that needs to be unique to me.

Comment: What range of values can dimension1...dimensionN be?

Comment: @tadman: using a sha1 hash as the unique constraint looks the most promissing. I normally use 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID=LAST_INSERT_ID(ID)' to get the ID of either the inserted row or the ID of the existing row. Problem is though that the hash needs to be the unique column and i can't make the ID a primary key as MySql complains about it.... Any thoughts on how to fix this? So i need the hash to be unique and to be able to retrieve the ID of the existing row...if it already exists..

Comment: If you can deal with the Earth-hit-by-asteroid probability level of a collision, you might want to use SHA256 identifiers as your row's primary key and forget the compound key entirely. Just do a straight up `INSERT IGNORE` at that point. Be sure to test this strategy with significantly more data than you're ever intending to store to be sure it holds up under scale.

Answer (score 0):

Option1:

```
CREATE TABLE bigboy (
  ledger_sub1 int unsigned not null COMMENT 'foreign key me...',
  ledger_sub2 int unsigned not null COMMENT 'forgein key me...'
  PRIMARY KEY (ledger_sub1,ledger_sub2)
)

CREATE TABLE bigboy_sub1 {
 ledger int unsigned auto_increment,
 dim01 int unsigned not null,
 ...
 dim15 int unsigned not null,
 PRIMARY KEY (ledger),
 UNIQUE KEY uk1 (dim01..dim15)
)

CREATE TABLE bigboy_sub2 {
 ledger int unsigned auto_increment,
 dim16 int unsigned not null,
 ...
 dim30 int unsigned not null,
 PRIMARY KEY (ledger),
 UNIQUE KEY uk1 (dim16..dim30)
)

ledger_sub1 = INSERT IGNORE INTO bigboy_sub1(dim01..dim15) and return ledger;
ledger_sub2 = INSERT IGNORE INTO bigboy_sub2(dim16..dim30) and return ledger;
its_unique = INSERT IGNORE INTO bigboy(ledger_sub1,ledger_sub2);
```

Option2:

```
CREATE TABLE bigboy {
 ledger int unsigned auto_increment,
 dim01 int unsigned not null,
 ...
 dim30 int unsigned not null,
 bigboy_uniq VARCHAR(301) not null,
 PRIMARY KEY (ledger),
 UNIQUE KEY uk1 (bigboy_uniq)
);
where bigboy_uniq = concatenation of LPAD'ed dim01..dim30
```

Option3:

```
CREATE TABLE bigboy {
 ledger int unsigned auto_increment,
 dim01 int unsigned not null,
 ...
 dim30 int unsigned not null,
 fingers_crossed VARCHAR(32) not null,
 PRIMARY KEY (ledger),
 UNIQUE KEY uk1 (fingers_crossed)
);
where fingers_crossed = md5 of LPAD'ed dim01..dim30 string
```

(disclaimer - i wouldn't use any these alone unless hacking around)

Comment: Nice and clear explanation, thanks! i'll try it out :-)